# sql query select between two tables and update data between that two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 databases with same table name,

Database one name DB1 with table name **table1** :

```
id| dv_no | name

1 | 15-101| mics
```

Database two name DB2 with table name **table1** :

```
id| dv_no | name

1 | 16-101| juan
```

Both dv_no is unique in both database.

My question is I want a query to select between two table in different database and update the name fields using dynamic dv_no as condition

Comment: Is it MySQL or Postgres or both?

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please add the tag for the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the values using below query

```
Update db1.table1 set db1.table1.name=db2.table1.dv_no where db1.table1.dv_no=db2.table1.dv_no
```

You can select using below query

```
Select * from db1.table1
Union all
Select * from db2.table1
```

Comment: i mean i need to select dv_no fields between two database and update the field name if the select find the dv_no.

Comment: based in your query. it updates data from other tables.